# Сложить значения 2 массивов по ключам

Tags: php, json

Доброе времени суток!
Не могу сложить одинаковые ключи 2 массивов.
Допустим нужно сложить Total из 2 массивов где user Иванов Петр
1 массив:

```html
[
{
"user": "Иванов Петр",
"Department": "man",
"Total": 485094,
"Addon_1": "/images/user/user.jpg",
"Addon_2": "2",
"Addon_3": "/user/user.jpg",
"topuser": "Иванов Петр",
"_4025": 485094,
"_4012": 31,
"B_4012": 484412,
"_4011": 55,
"B_4011": 304,
"_4014": 185,
"B_4014": 272,
"_4013": 106,
"B_4013": 106
},
{
"user": "Иванова Ольга",
"Department": "man",
"Total": 189601,
"Addon_1": "/images/user/user.jpg",
"Addon_2": "2",
"Addon_3": "/user/user.jpg",
"topuser": "Иванова Ольга",
"_4025": 485094,
"_4012": 17,
"B_4012": 189056,
"_4014": 169,
"B_4014": 323,
"_4011": 40,
"B_4011": 118,
"_4013": 104,
"B_4013": 104
}
]
```

2 массив:

```html
[
{
"user": "Иванов Петр",
"Department": "",
"Total": 5116,
"_1011": 35,
"_1012": 26,
"_1013": 0,
"_1014": 0,
"_1015": 4,
"_1016": 1,
"_2021": 3,
"_2022": 54,
"_3031": 0,
"_3032": 0,
"_3033": 0,
"_3034": 0,
"_3035": 0,
"_3036": 0,
"_3039": 85,
"_4011": 0,
"_4012": 0,
"_4013": 0,
"_4014": 0,
"B_1011": 35,
"B_1012": 26,
"B_1013": 0,
"B_1014": 0,
"B_1015": 80,
"B_1016": 20,
"B_2021": 90,
"B_2022": 810,
"B_3031": 0,
"B_3032": 0,
"B_3033": 0,
"B_3034": 0,
"B_3035": 0,
"B_3036": 0,
"B_3039": 4055,
"B_4011": 0,
"B_4012": 0,
"B_4013": 0,
"B_4014": 0,
"Addon_1": "/images/user/user.jpg",
"Addon_2": "",
"Addon_3": "/user/user.jpg"
},
{
"user": "Иванова Ольга",
"Department": "",
"Total": 3051,
"_1011": 21,
"_1012": 4,
"_1013": 0,
"_1014": 0,
"_1015": 9,
"_1016": 0,
"_2021": 2,
"_2022": 10,
"_3031": 0,
"_3032": 0,
"_3033": 0,
"_3034": 0,
"_3035": 0,
"_3036": 0,
"_3039": 32,
"_4011": 0,
"_4012": 0,
"_4013": 0,
"_4014": 0,
"B_1011": 21,
"B_1012": 4,
"B_1013": 0,
"B_1014": 0,
"B_1015": 180,
"B_1016": 0,
"B_2021": 60,
"B_2022": 150,
"B_3031": 0,
"B_3032": 0,
"B_3033": 0,
"B_3034": 0,
"B_3035": 0,
"B_3036": 0,
"B_3039": 2636,
"B_4011": 0,
"B_4012": 0,
"B_4013": 0,
"B_4014": 0,
"Addon_1": "/user/user.jpg",
"Addon_2": "",
"Addon_3": "/user/user.jpg"
}
]
```

$data - 1 массив
$data2 - 2 массив

```html
$data3 = array_merge_recursive ($data, $data2);




?>
<table class="highlight centered">
<thead class="orange darken-2">
<tr>
<th>Место</th>
<th>Картинка</th>
<th>Юзер</th>
<th>Очки</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php

//Вывод данных статистики
foreach ($data3 as $key => $value)
{
if ($value['Department'] == ""){


echo '

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>'.$n++.'</td>
<td><img class="circle responsive-img" style="max-width: 50px "src="'.$value['Addon_3'].'"></td>
<td>'.$value['user'].'</td>
<td>'.$value['Total'].'</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
';
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data1 = json_decode($data1, false);
$data2 = json_decode($data2, false);

$data3 = array_merge_recursive($data1, $data2);

 foreach($data3 as $key => $value) {
     echo $value->total; 
 }
```

Выведет первый раз 485... Второй раз 511...

Вы получаете `json` данные, и пытаетесь сразу с ними работать, а в них к тому-же есть объект, по этому сначала их надо перевести к данным удобным для работы в `PHP`.

Comment: Не, у меня они приведены к удобным данным, я сюда просто не выложил это. Суть в том что не суммируются данные а выводятся 2 раза. "Total": 485094 (1 массива) + "Total": 5116,(2 массива) где "user": "Иванов Петр" и так по всему массиву.

Comment: Как тогда выглядит массив в вашем приведении, сделайте `print_r($data)` и выложите на pastebin.com если вам неудобно сюда.

Comment: У меня просто слишком большой объем данных если я выведу его. Суть в том что он не суммирует данные а добавляет их в массив. Т.е. было [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/j9fryKv5) ( 1 массив ) а при array_merge_recursive со 2 массивом стало [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/bSsG7zk0) . Получается он не суммировал данные а сложил 2 массива в 1.

Comment: Может ли кто подсказать?